# Select a class under an active accordion panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to load data into a table in the accordion panel once it's clicked. I've tried a number of different ways and tried to find it in the DOM object, but I just can't find how to access it directly. It's not complicated, but I've probably just overly confused myself to the point where I'm going in circles.

I have a basic accordion:

```
<div id="bb-content">
   <h3 data-category="cat1">Name1</h3>
   <div>
      <table class="bb-table">
         <tbody class="bb-content">
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <h3 data-category="cat2">Name2</h3>
   <div>
      <table class="bb-table">
         <tbody class="bb-content-body">
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
....
</div>
```

etc.

Built with this jQuery UI method

```
$('#bb-content').accordion({ 
   active: false,
   collapsible: true,
   heightStyle: "content",
   beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
      var cat = ui.newHeader.data("category");
      var tbody = $(this).find('.bb-content-body');                     

      //if(!$.trim( tbody.html() ).length) {
         tbody.load("/ajax/bb", {'cat': cat});
      //}
   }
});
```

This is the most working version I have. I've tried a number of other things, but this works somewhat. And what I want to do is the commented out part, but it selects all the classes (like it should) instead of just the first one below the H3.

Basically, I want to query the ajax page only once per panel.

Using jQuery-UI 1.10.4

Comment: So what's wrong with `$(this).find('.bb-content-body');`?

Comment: @ShaunakD it finds all of the classes and sets them all, instead of just the first one. Which means, the commented out part never works because it always has content that was previously loaded in another accordion panel, instead of the specific content based on the category in `data-*`. I only want the first one under the `H3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var tbody = ui.newHeader.next().find('.bb-content-body');
```

instead of

```
var tbody = $(this).find('.bb-content-body');
```

**Reason** : `$(this)` refers `$('#bb-content')`, while you need current accordion header use `ui.newHeader`